# setInterval() will not run immediately

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I want to define a object that hold a interval that can be reset

```
var intervalHolder = {
    make : function() {
        this.clean();
        this.interval = setInterval(function () {
            console.log("make interval");
        }, 3.0 * 1000);
    },
    clean: function(){
        if(this.interval){
            console.log("clean interval");
            clearInterval(this.interval);
        }
    }
};
```

`intervalHolder.make()` was designed to clean old interval and make a new one

but I found that when invoke the `intervalHolder.make()` multiple times , there will be a time gap between log `clean interval` and `make interval`, not immediately as expected. is clearInterval()' too time consuming?

Comment: Yes, that's the interval. It doesn't run immediately and it is the expected behaviour.

Comment: no clearInterval() is not consuming the time, but intervalHolder.make() is consuming the time. In your case when you call this.clean(); it calls immediately and log the statement clean interval, but your next log which is in this.interval will call after time you gave to setInterval. So there is a time gap between these logs.